# Source of passwd error messages

Tags: ubuntu, password, source, passwd, setuid

I am testing if the `passwd` command could run if the setuid bit is disabled. I disabled the setuid by running the following command:

```bash
chmod 0554 /bin/passwd
```

After doing so, I tested if the `passwd` command would still be able to function. But as expected, it didn't. Instead, it gave me the following errors:

```
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

```
passwd: password unchanged
```

I tried to look for these error messages in the source code, but I couldn't find them in [this](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/passwd.c) file. Can anyone please direct me to find the source file that contains the error messages shown above?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first error message is from the PAM library, see e.g. https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/libpam/pam_strerror.c

```
const char *pam_strerror(pam_handle_t *pamh UNUSED, int errnum)
{
    switch (errnum) {
/* ... */
    case PAM_AUTHTOK_ERR:
      return _("Authentication token manipulation error");
/* ... */
    }

    return _("Unknown PAM error");
}
```

A search in the linked Git repository finds the second error message in
https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/libmisc/pam_pass.c

This is the function that prints both error messages:

```
void do_pam_passwd (const char *user, bool silent, bool change_expired)
{
    pam_handle_t *pamh = NULL;
    int flags = 0, ret;
    FILE *shadow_logfd = log_get_logfd();

    if (silent)
        flags |= PAM_SILENT;
    if (change_expired)
        flags |= PAM_CHANGE_EXPIRED_AUTHTOK;

    ret = pam_start ("passwd", user, &conv, &pamh);
    if (ret != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf (shadow_logfd,
             _("passwd: pam_start() failed, error %d\n"), ret);
        exit (10);  /* XXX */
    }

    ret = pam_chauthtok (pamh, flags);
    if (ret != PAM_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf (shadow_logfd, _("passwd: %s\n"), pam_strerror (pamh, ret));
        fputs (_("passwd: password unchanged\n"), shadow_logfd);
        pam_end (pamh, ret);
        exit (10);  /* XXX */
    }

    fputs (_("passwd: password updated successfully\n"), shadow_logfd);
    (void) pam_end (pamh, PAM_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I hope you're doing that for educational experience, and not because you think it will improve security or something (it would make it much worse!)

That being said, few pointers to handling that and similar situation in the future generically:

- `strace -ff -efile passwd` will show you what files `passwd(1)` is trying to access, including which libraries and extra executables are being used etc.
- then you can find source files for that commands and libraries (via `dpkg -S /path/to/file` and `apt-get source packagename` on Debian derivatives like Ubuntu)
- then you can `grep(1)` those sources for those messages that the command spewed out.

Comment: Thanks for the response :). Yes, I am doing it for educational purposes. Well, to be exact for research purposes to develop a more secure and easy-to-use tool as a replacement for sudo. You can check it out in https://github.com/SamerW/RootAsRole/tree/master/ebpf